# AWS-SDK: Error executing GetObjectAcl got an AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk, ibm-cloud-storage

My main goal is to get the ACL info on a specific object.

```php
$fileSystem = Storage::disk("s3");
$adapter = $fileSystem->getAdapter();
$client = $adapter->getClient();
$objectInfo = $client->getObjectAcl(
  [
    'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
    'Key'    => "key-name",
  ]
);
```

When running, I get the error :

```xml
Aws/S3/Exception/S3Exception with message 'Error executing "GetObjectAcl" ...
resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Error> 
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    < (truncated...)AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message> 
 <Resource>
```

Any idea to resolve it would be thankful.

Comment: Is [S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) enabled on this bucket? Also, see [How do I troubleshoot 403 Access Denied errors from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your comment. Actually yes it's enabled

Comment: It seems an IAM Policy issue to me either S3 bucket doesnt have access or User by which you are running the CLI not having enough permission.

Comment: You originally indicated that getObject was successful but that getObjectAcl returned 403 Access Denied. Are you now saying both fail with 403 Access Denied?

Comment: @jarmod Nop, just the `getObjectAcl` which returned a 403 access denied.

Comment: Does your IAM principal actually have `s3:GetObjectAcl` permission on the object in question?

Comment: @jarmod I can confirm the presence of the object within the bucket and the bucket access policy is public for reading objects

Comment: When you make API calls to S3, as you are doing, they are signed with your AWS credentials. Those credentials need `s3:GetObjectAcl` permission on the object in question. Repeating my previous question: do they have this permission?

Comment: Thank u guys, I've resolved via making the policy beyond the writer role to complete privileged actions as defined by service with the role `MANAGER` then it works as excepted.