# AWS-SDK: Executing GetObject() gets an Empty Stream

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

My main objective is to get the info on a specific object.

```php
$client = $adapter->getClient();
$objectInfo = $client->getObject(
    [
        'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
        'Key'    => "key-name",
    ]
);

dd($objectInfo->toArray()["Body"]);
```

When running, i got as a result :

```php
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {
  -stream: stream resource {
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

Any idea to resolve it would be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to call getContents() method from the object. for more inputs please refer the below page
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-GuzzleHttp.Psr7.Stream.html#_getContents

$objectInfo['Body']->getContents();

Comment: I appreciate your help, it does indeed work. when u got a few minutes would u check to please [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908110/aws-sdk-error-executing-getobjectacl-got-an-accessdenied) it's related to the GeObjectAcl